# Group by with joins in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two table

```
table 1: has_many table2
table1 fields are id,name,amount, contract_id

table 2: belongs to table1
table2 fields are id,name,table1_id
```

Let's take example
Table 1 one record have 3 records in table2
  Table1.where(contract_id: 2).table2.counts = 3

```
  Table1.where(contract_id: 2) = id:2, name: "abc", amount= 100, contract_id: 2
  Table1.where(contract_id: 2).table2 = id:1, name: "abc1", table1_id: 2
                          id:2, name: "abc2", table1_id: 2
                          id:3, name: "abc3", table1_id: 2
```

When i am trying to do group by with joins it makes problem

```
Table1.joins(:table2).where(contract_id: 2).group(:name).sum(:amount)
I want result here ["abc", 100]
But its give me ["abc", 300]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure exactly why you are opting for `group` here. You are just fetching data from `Table1`. So this can be done as `Table1.joins(:table2).where(id: 2).uniq`

Comment: @dkp Actullay i am working on report so i am getting filter result data in one variable and reuse this 
So ine first query i am using join with many table

But when i using group by at some stage it give me proper result

Comment: Why are you using `sum` in this case? It seems like maybe you're just after the actual value in `table1.amount`. What if you just selected name & amount, rather than summing & grouping, is that what you're after?

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz I am findind records from table where contract_id = 2

So this query have 4 records
and when i am applying group by with sum it makes me problem

Comment: You do not show in your question which records have contract_id 2. Please answer what you are trying to do with your `sum` and your `group`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming standard Rails conventions here in that `Table1.table_name` is `table1s` (pluralized). This answer needs modifying if you have set it up differently.

You are `group`ing by `:name`. Rails assumes you mean `"table1s.name"` since that is the model generating the query. Are you trying to group by `table2s.name`? If so you have to specify that explicitly:

```
Table1.joins(:table2).where(id: 2).group("table2s.name").sum(:amount)
```

Similarly, `where(id: 2)` refers to `table1`, but I think in this case that is what you mean, correct?

Comment: What is the fill output when you do the above? I did not create tables to test this example.

Answer (score -2):

this is a wrong way: try this if you want to fetch only table_id: 2

```
Table1.joins(:table2).where(table2: {table1_id: 2}).group(:name).sum(:amount)
```

Comment: `where(id: 2)` in this statement is functionally equivalent to `where(table2: { table1_id: 2})` should suffice for that since `id` here refers to a column on `table1` and it's already being joined on `table1.id = table2.table1_id`.